# Styled-components organization

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to use styled-components in my app and I am wondering how to organize it.

Basically styled-components are assigned to specific component for reusability.

But what about styled-components which I would like to use many times in other components (for example animations components)?
Should I create a file where I will keep these 'global' styled-components and import it to many components?

Is it good practice?

Comment: I just use a component-per-file way. It is convenient to keep components seperated and allows importing only needed components instead of all files.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This is what most of my big production applications built with styled-components look like:

```
src
├── App
│   ├── Header
│   │   ├── Logo.js    
│   │   ├── Title.js   
│   │   ├── Subtitle.js
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── Footer
│       ├── List.js
│       ├── ListItem.js
│       ├── Wrapper.js
│       └── index.js
├── shared
│   ├── Button.js
│   ├── Card.js
│   ├── InfiniteList.js
│   ├── EmojiPicker
│   └── Icons
└── index.js
```

The `App` folder contains all the specific components that make up your bigger application. (you might structure that by route in your real app) Each of those bigger components is a folder with an `index.js` file and a bunch of styled components in individual files.

While I'm building my application and I notice I need a styled component from one bigger component in another bigger component, I drag its file to the `shared/` folder, update all the imports and that's it! Over time `shared/` becomes an improptu pattern library with all of the components I want/need to reuse throughout my entire app.

Another way that's fairly common is to have `style.js` files in the component folders which contains all of the styled components of that component. The upside being that you have less files that get in your way, but with the downside that it's harder to notice duplication and moving components into the shared folder is more work.

I personally use the first version more often than not, but that's probably just a matter of taste—try them both and see which one you like more!

Comment: @mxstbr. Does that structure isolate styled components from native components? In my current projects, I have styled components coupled with native components in the same file and from experience I can tell this really gets messy, On the other hand, if I isolate styled components in separate files, I will end up with loads of files. Imagine having an individual file for each `<div>` wrapper in your templates, that would be an overkill. What are you suggestions for that point?

Comment: @mxstbr don't you have a seperate folder for containers, and where would you put your individual page components such as eg. Home.jsx? Also don't you separate the styled-components from rest of your presentational components?

Answer (score 43):

You can also try [Atomic Design](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) to structure your app. This way you will be able to reuse your styled components. Based on Atomic Design methodology, you organize your components into atoms, molecules, organisms, pages and templates.

**Atom**

An atom is native html tag. For example, an Input element can be an Atom

```
const Input = props => <input {...props} />
```

**Molecules**

Group of atoms is a molecule. For example:

```
const Field = ({ label, ...inputProps }) => (
    <Label>
        {label}
        <Input {...inputProps} />
    </Label>
)
```

**Organisms**

Organism is a group of atoms, molecules and/or other organisms. For example:

```
const Form = (props) => (
    <form {...props}>
        <Field label="Name" type="text" />
        <Field label="Email" type="email" />
    </form>
)
```

**Pages**

A page is where you will put mostly organisms. For example:

```
const HomePage = () => (
    <PageTemplate header={<Header />}>
        <Form />
    </PageTemplate>
)
```

**Templates**

A template is a layout to be used on pages. For example:

```
const PageTemplate = ({ header, children }) => (
    <main>
        {header && <div>{header}</div>}
        {children}
    </main>
)
```

**Github example**

There is a React starter project on Github that uses Atomic Design methodology with styled-components integration. Here is the [Link](https://github.com/diegohaz/arc).

Comment: Now! that is a very interesting thing, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 21):

The way i am organizing my Project with styled-component is the following:

```
src
├── Layout
│   ├── Header
│   │   ├── Logo.jsx    
│   │   ├── styled.js
│   │   ├── container.js
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── LeftPanel
│       ├── LeftPanel.jsx
│       ├── styled.js
│       └── index.js
└── index.js
```

Reasoning:

- Each folder is a feature.
- Each file within a folder have a responsability.

  - `.jsx` represent a presentational component.
  - `styled.js` are styled components. Manage only how components look. Also any theme related file should be imported here, such as colors,borderStyles, etc.
  - `container.js` If we are using any state management we should have an artifact connecting our components with that library. In this case Redux.
  - `index.js` exports whatever is relevant.

The advantage that i see with this approach is that is pretty clear where changes have to be made if you decide to use another CSSinJS library.

Hope it make sense for someone else.

Cheers!

Comment: I prefer this one.

Comment: I like your structure, but what if we have something like buttons and inputs that are shared between features, where we should put those components?